# Laravel 5 query builder and NOW() for date comparison

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

My database (MySQL) has a timestamp field for `created_at`.

I have two entries, with the timestamps as follows:

- 2017-12-12 18:25:00
- 2016-10-02 18:00:00

Today is 2016-10-19 (for future reference). If I use the following query, I get no results:

```
    $job = $jobs->where('closing_at', '>=', 'NOW()')
            ->orderBy($sorter[0], $sorter[1])->paginate(24);
```

If I hardcode the date, I get the correct results, just the one future date:

```
    $job = $jobs->where('closing_at', '>=', "2016-10-19 00:00:00")
            ->orderBy($sorter[0], $sorter[1])->paginate(24);
```

I'm assuming my error is in the use of `NOW()` with the Eloquent query builder but I can't figure out the correct way to use this is.

Comment: DB::raw or whereRaw should help you https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Instead of NOW(), i guess you need \Carbon::now()

Comment: use date("Y-m-d H:i:s") or \Carbon::now()

Comment: Hey, I was wondering the same thing, turns out you can just use \DB::raw('now()')

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eloquent Query builder doesn't accept those specific SQL functions but as it's done within your PHP you can easily use the great Carbon Class : http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ :

`use Carbon\Carbon;`

And then,

```
$job = $jobs->where('closing_at', '>=', Carbon::now())
        ->orderBy($sorter[0], $sorter[1])->paginate(24);
```

That should do the trick.

There is also a whereDate() eloquent method : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses

Comment: That does it. Doesn't make sense to me that Eloquent doesn't accept the basic SQL function, but it works. thanks

Comment: That'd work on the DB:: object : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries but not on a modal called by eloquent because it's "managed by PHP" in the first place.